# programatically Import Magento 1 orders into Magento 2 site

Tags: magento, magento2

I have exported **Magento-1** Order details into csv file.

I Need to import those order details into **Magento2** site via programatically.
I can able to update the order grand total already present in the orders.

Need to create a order programatically,

Here i have mentioned the Order update code

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
$orderId = 000000002;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
$order->setGrandTotal(50.00);
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
$order->save();
echo "Order Updated successfully";
```

Can anyone suggest some ideas for create order via similar method.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can just install [this](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/) tool and configure this 
after that you can select order, catalog, etc to import in your Magento2 store from Magento1

Comment: Why should we use this tool when Magento itself provides great Data Migration Tool. I have used your mention tool personally and It will not be working as expected. So finally I have used Magento's default Migration Tool and its work great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento's default migration tool. Which can not even orders but it will import the products, attributes, attributes set etc. Almost all the data from Magento 1 to Magento 2. You can select what you want to migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

I had personally used it and it's really work fine. Below is the URL it may help you.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Comment: How to migrate only customers n sales orders?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. But before explain it properly I need to know are you aware of Magento Data Migration Tool?

Comment: Yes, i migrated all data using data migration tool, but i need to migrate only customer and sales order data.

Comment: Great. please follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173537/how-to-migrate-only-orders-with-data-migration-tool. It will definitely help you. Don't confuse with its name. Whenever we try to migrate the orders we require customers too. So it will help you to migrate both the things together.